# Transfer polygon information to point later using STContains()

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, intersection

I would like to build a query that will transfer information from a polygon layer (~1100 records) to a point layer (~300 points). I want `Comp_Numb` and `Stand_Number` values to be transferred to the points layer when a new point is added to the database.

I have built the following query (it is a select query but I will change it to an update query when it is working properly):

```
SELECT GPS.Invent_Plot_ID, stands.Comp_Numb, stands.Stand_Number
FROM FORESTRY.dbo.[GSCA #] AS stands
INNER JOIN GPS_DATA.dbo.GPS_Forest_Inventory_test AS GPS
    ON stands.Geometry.STContains(stands.Geometry) = 1
```

When I run the query it returns >590,000 records. I have looked around at examples such as [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23959/how-to-get-point-attribute-from-polygon-layer/146215).

Where do I go next?

Comment: `stands.Geometry.STContains(stands.Geometry)` will always be true. Are you sure that you don't mean for one of those to be `GPS.geometry` (or whatever the geometry column in that table is called)?

Comment: Oh right...yes you are correct. I did mean for it to be stands.Geometry.STContains(gps.Geometry) = 1. I think we have solved it. The code we used: 
'UPDATE gps
 SET gps.Comp_Numb = stands.Comp_Numb
 FROM GPS_DATA.dbo.GPS_FORESTRY_INVENTORY AS gps
 INNER JOIN FORESTRY.dbo.[GSCA #] AS stands
  ON stands.Geometry.STContains(gps.Geometry) = 1
  WHERE gps.Ownership LIKE 'GSCA'
The problem we found was the spatial reference for the gps layer was not set properly.
Thanks for your help